# readxlsx function limitations in openxlsx library

Tags: r, openxlsx

When I try to import an excel worksheet with readxlsx function it can be observed that in the preview there are more than 100 columns inserted into the data frame. But when I look inside the data frame, only the first 100 columns are visible. Thus, adding some columns and then using writexlsx is omitting those columns. Is there any way to avoid this situation?

Regards,
Rafał

Comment: There's another package called `readxl` that you can try https://readxl.tidyverse.org/